# Opencv function equal for matlab sortrows

Tags: android, matlab, sorting, opencv

I have an 2D array type `Mat` in my Android OpenCV project, and I need to sort the array in the same manner as the MATLAB `sortrows` function. I found the `Core.sort()` function that takes flags like `Sort_Every_Row`.  This seems to be the one I want, but when I use this method I get different output results from the ones I get from MATLAB.

Is there any other function, or any other ways to do this kind of sort? Do I have to write the method from scratch?

Below is the line I use for sorting my array FeatureMatirx :

```
Core.sort(FeatureMatrix, FeatureMatrix, Core.SORT_EVERY_ROW);
```

Edit : 
Let Me Explain With A Simple Example:

```
Mat test = new Mat(4,3, CvType.CV_64FC1);
test.put(0, 0, 1);
test.put(0, 1, 2);
test.put(0, 2, 3);
test.put(1, 0, 1);
test.put(1, 1, 1);
test.put(1, 2, 1);
test.put(2, 0, 2);
test.put(2, 1, 1);
test.put(2, 2, 3);
test.put(3, 0, 1);
test.put(3, 1, 2);
test.put(3, 2, 1);

Core.sort(test, test,Core.SORT_EVERY_ROW + Core.SORT_ASCENDING);

for (int k = 0; k < test.rows(); k++) {
    Log.i("Test", test.get(k, 0)[0] + " " + test.get(k, 1)[0]+ " " +test.get(k, 2)[0]);
}
```

and the result of above example is this:

```
03-05 21:32:01.893: I/Test(1323): 1.0 2.0 3.0
03-05 21:32:01.893: I/Test(1323): 1.0 1.0 1.0
03-05 21:32:01.893: I/Test(1323): 1.0 2.0 3.0
03-05 21:32:01.893: I/Test(1323): 1.0 1.0 2.0
```

but sortrows in matlab result as below:

```
1     1     1
1     2     1
1     2     3
2     1     3
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/):

> The function sort sorts each matrix row or each matrix column in ascending or descending order. So you should pass two operation flags to get desired behaviour.

Thus, you need to pass a sort ordering flag as well. Since MATLAB's [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) sorts in ascending order, pass the appropriate flag:

```
Core.sort(FeatureMatrix, FeatureMatrix, Core.SORT_EVERY_ROW + Core.SORT_ASCENDING);
```

Comment: This isn't the same as sortrows. This will sort rows in the sense it goes row by row and sorts all the elements in each row. Matlab sortrows will swap rows around so that each preceding row will be "smaller" in the sense that either the first column will be lower, or if equal, the second column will be lower and so on. The does not change the order of columns in each row, and ony whole rows are moved.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I decide to write the sort method from scratch and the working result become something like the below code:

```
private Mat SortRows(Mat FeatureMatrix)
{
        // Sorting
        Mat SortedFeatureMatrix = new Mat(FeatureMatrix.rows(),FeatureMatrix.cols(), FeatureMatrix.type());
        FeatureMatrix.row(0).copyTo(SortedFeatureMatrix.row(0));
        for (int i = 1; i < FeatureMatrix.rows(); i++) {
            int index = i;
            while(index>0)
            {
                boolean cmp = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < FeatureMatrix.cols(); j++) {
                    if(FeatureMatrix.get(i, j)[0]==SortedFeatureMatrix.get(index-1, j)[0])
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if(FeatureMatrix.get(i, j)[0]<SortedFeatureMatrix.get(index-1, j)[0])
                    {
                        cmp = true;
                        SortedFeatureMatrix.row(index-1).copyTo(SortedFeatureMatrix.row(index));
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(FeatureMatrix.get(i, j)[0]>SortedFeatureMatrix.get(index-1, j)[0])
                    {
                        cmp = false;
                        FeatureMatrix.row(i).copyTo(SortedFeatureMatrix.row(index));
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(cmp == true)
                {
                    index-=1;
                    if(index == 0)
                    {
                        FeatureMatrix.row(i).copyTo(SortedFeatureMatrix.row(index));
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return SortedFeatureMatrix;
}
```

maybe this help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

This is a efficient recursive algorithm which use openCV sortIdx function:

```
Mat SortRows(Mat FeatureMatrix,Mat &index,int direction){

Mat main_column=FeatureMatrix.col(0);//Extract Main column
sortIdx(main_column,index,direction+CV_SORT_EVERY_COLUMN);//Sort Main column
Mat sorted_FeatureMatrix=indexing(FeatureMatrix,index);//Sort Whole FeatureMatrix based on Sorted Main Column index
if (FeatureMatrix.cols==1)//last column
    return sorted_FeatureMatrix;
//Check identical consecutive elements in Main Column and sort them baesd on next columns
int start=-1;
int end=-1;
for(int i=0;i<sorted_FeatureMatrix.rows;i++)
{
    if((i!=sorted_FeatureMatrix.rows-1)&&(sorted_FeatureMatrix.at<float>(i,0)==sorted_FeatureMatrix.at<float>(i+1,0)))
    {
        if(start==-1) start=i;
        end=i+1;
    }
    else 
        if(start!=-1)//if Start has been set
        {//Seperate next columns of rows(start:end) and Sort them based on next columns
            Mat partial_FeatureMatrix=sorted_FeatureMatrix(Range(start,end+1),Range(1,FeatureMatrix.cols));
            Mat partial_index=index.rowRange(start,end+1);
            Mat temportal_index;
            Mat sorted_partial_FeatureMatrix=SortRows(partial_FeatureMatrix,temportal_index,direction);
            sorted_partial_FeatureMatrix.copyTo(sorted_FeatureMatrix(Range(start,end+1),Range(1,FeatureMatrix.cols)));
            Mat sorted_partial_index=indexing(partial_index,temportal_index);
            sorted_partial_index.copyTo(index.rowRange(start,end+1));
            start=-1;
            end=-1;
        }
}
return sorted_FeatureMatrix;}
```